# how to interpret ISO2768-mK angular tolerance

Tags: design, mechanical, technical-drawing, drafting, tolerance

How to apply tolerance for angle based on ISO-2768-mK? Cause I am confused about the statement "Permissible deviations in degrees and minutes for ranges in nominal lengths". Lets say I have a countersunk hole with ⌀3.6 and 90°, what would be the tolerance for the 90°? Thank you.

[*example added, not by OP*]: Typical language and table from public sources, reproducing the paywalled ISO standard:
[image: a]

In older (1989,1993) versions of the ISO2768-1 which can be found on google, the language describing the row headings of table 3 is a little more specific:

> Permissible deviations for ranges of lengths, in millimetres, of the shorter side of the angle concerned

Comment: I made an answer but deleted it because not sure of exact reference length definition. But pretty confident that the reference length for tolerancing the 90 degree arc per the standard, must live in the same plane as the angle, which is the cross-section view of the hole/csk (i.e. not the top-view where diameter of hole/csk itself is commonly defined)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering my question. Based on the 2D I shared below, could you advise me the tolerance to apply for Dim 19 based on ISO2768mK? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you want, post this as a new question, and reference this question to say it's a follow up. Sorry I added so much stuff to your original Q, but this one actually might be quite useful to people in the future

Comment: Also your countersink is ⌀5.4, not ⌀3.6